# How do you mock/stub class instantiation with SinonJS?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, mocking, sinon

How do you mock or stub class instantiation with SinonJS? I want to make assertions on the parameters that are passed to the constructor.

```
var myClass = new MyClass({ params: "To Test" } ); // how can I mock the 'new' on MyClass?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What do you do in the constructor? Do you assign the parameters to the MyClass object? If so,

```
var params = {param: 'To Test'};
myClass = new MyClass(params);
```

Then check that `myClass.param = params.param`.

Calling `var myClass = new MyClass(params)` is the same as calling

```
var myClass = {};
MyClass.call(myClass, params);
myClass.__proto__ = MyClass.prototype; //This is considered bad practice, but is fine for testing.
```

Is this what you're asking? If not, what kinds of assertions on parameters are you hoping to make?

Comment: Doesn't new also clone / make a new instantiation separate from the original such that the "new"-ed object does not share any of the same member variables as the original?

Comment: That said, it seems odd to be testing this. It's like doing `var x=2` then checking `x===2`.

Comment: Thanks! Of course my actual test is not as trivial as this. I have class A instantiating class B and I want to verify that class A  is passing the right parameters during instantiation.